# Using VBA to save an attachment as a different filetype

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a macro to save html attachments as .txt files (and then do some stuff with the .txt file) but am running into a problem right out of the gate - the Attachment object only has the SaveAsFile method, not the SaveAs method, and the SaveAsFile method only has the path parameter, not the type parameter.

I've tried various methods of just sneaking .txt into the pathname, and none have worked.

This is my first attempt at "serious" programming, so it's possible I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Comment: I would start by doing the `SaveAsFile` method. Then doing some code which will convert the file into the `.txt` file. Have the code kill the previous file as when you save as the old copy will still be there. Then you are free to do what you want with the `.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the desired extension for the file. The [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Attachment class saves the attachment to the specified path (with the specified filename).

You may also find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: When I try that, I've alternatively received runtime error '-2147024809 (80070057)' or just had nothing happen.

Here's an example of one of my attempts. This one led to that error message:

`Sub SaveAsText()
    `Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    `Dim myAttachment As Attachment
    
        `Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
       `Set myAttachment = myItem.Attachments(1)
        
        
        `myAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\C63925\Documents" & myItem.Subject & ".txt"
               
    `End Sub

Comment: Make sure that the subject field doesn't include forbidden symbols. Try to specify any simple name first and see whether it works. For example: "D:\hello.txt"